# selection.data returning different types of objects

Tags: javascript, d3.js, web-inspector

Every loop, I perform some updates on a certain selection of objects (see code snippet below), starting with removing deleted elements using an `exit()` call.  I just added a slider to modify a parameter in one of the objects, and when the slider moves I call the same update method (again with the code below).  When the slider triggers the update, however, the selection is different... and in particular, the `exit()` method fails --- `TypeError: selection.exit is not a function` (and [I think I'm avoiding the standard cause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596908/d3-typeerror-link-exit-is-not-a-function-link-exit-remove-what-am-i-doing) of that problem).

```
var selection = svgSim.selectAll(".bh")
    .data(binary);

// Remove old
console.log("sel = ", selection);
var olds = selection.exit();
olds.remove();
```

When I log the `selection` to console, the contents is basically the same... but there seems to be something different about the object type, or something like that.  See the screen shot below.  The first printout of `selection` ("sel = [...]") is when it *works* fine.  The next time it raises the error, and the formatting of the print is different - although it seems to contain the same basic data.

- Why is `selection.data()` returning different types of objects when called in different contexts?
- What is the difference in the `console.log` output: what is `pt` (in the output) and what are the different types of objects being printed here.

Note: *I understand if this non-MWE is insufficient to solve the problem entirely, which is why I've tried to ask a few specific (sub)questions which may help me find the problem, none-the-less.*

---

The data looks something like,

```
var phaseInit = Math.random();
var binary = [
    {name: "a", phase: phaseInit, mass: m1},
    {name: "b", phase: phaseInit + 0.5, mass: m2}
];
```

And when the slider moves, I'm modifying the data like:

```
binary[0].mass = sliderScaleM1.invert(sval);
```

*(very new to javascipt and d3)*

[image]

Comment: Why don't you create a snippet (the `<>` button) with a basic example reproducing the issue? Right now it's hard to tell how you're re-binding the data and updating the selection.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado thanks for taking a look.  I will try if need be... but it would be extremely difficult to produce a MWE without including the entire (thousands of lines) files.  I'm hoping that someone can recognize this type of problem based on the given information, or on other particular pieces of information that I can more easily provide (e.g. I've tried to include how the data is being changed)... if that is not the case: then I'll definitely have to work harder to produce a MWE.

Comment: The first `sel` in the console (19:57:07) is a D3 selection. The second one (19:57:12), however, is just an array, more specifically the data array. How are you changing `sel` in between them? There are missing pieces of information here, do you see? My guess here is that your're using `data` as a getter (`data()`), when it should be a **setter** (`data(binary)`).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Okay, I'll try harder on a MWE.  But the code which prints `sel = ` is shown above, and `selection` is defined in the same way at both calls... The second time, `selection.data(...)` is returning an array instead of a selection.  Are there certain times at which that happens?

Comment: As I said above, are you using `data` as a getter or as a setter? If you're using `var selection = svgSim.selectAll(".bh").data();` you **don't** have a D3 selectiion anymore.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I think that might be it, `binary` might have lost its value at some point so it became a `getter` effectively.

Comment: Well, if you always pass `binary` as the argument this is a mystery to me. I hope someone else finds out how you ended up with a getter.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado yes, you were right, thank you!  I'm happy to mark your answer as correct if you enter one

Comment: @GerardoFurtado okay... I see that you're trying to illustrate that more information was required, but actually... you were still able to answer my questions without it, and indeed I solved the problem using that information.  For which I am grateful, and believe is an example of posts without MWE still resolving themselves well and still being of benefit to others with similar problems.

Comment: Done, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we don't have access to a MWE ([see this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665302/selection-data-returning-different-types-of-objects-at-times-exit-is-not-a-fun#comment82290005_47665302)), this is a general answer trying to clarify the issue based on the information provided.

In D3, the `data()` method accepts three things:

1. An array;
2. A function;
3. Nothing.

In the first and second cases, `data()` is a **setter**. However, in the third case, `data()` is a **getter**.

We can see this in a basic example:

```js
var body = d3.select("body");
var data = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
var sel = body.selectAll(null)
  .data(data);
sel.enter()
  .append("p")
  .html(String)

console.log(sel)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

However, if we use `data()` as a getter, we don't have a selection anymore:

```js
var body = d3.select("body");
var data = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
var sel = body.selectAll(null)
  .data(data);
sel.enter()
  .append("p")
  .html(String)
var sel2 = body.selectAll("p").data()

console.log(sel2)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Because of that, you cannot call `exit()` on that variable: it is not a D3 selection, but just the data array.

Looking at your console we can see that, at `19:57:07`, `sel` is a regular D3 selection. However, at `19:57:12`, `sel` is just an array, more specifically your data array.

So, in conclusion, somehow in your code you're using `data()` as a getter, and the variable `sel` doesn't hold a D3 selection anymore.